# Transferring all music from iPhone to iPhone

Tags: itunes, iphone, music

I recently got a new iPhone and the music I downloaded on iTunes on my old iPhone downloaded on to my new iPhone perfectly fine. But the music I downloaded not on my iPhone doesn't download onto my new iPhone.

Hard to understand but to put it simply, I just want **all** my music on my new iPhone not just some it.

Comment: How do you got the music you didn't download onto your old iPhone? If you are not using iTunes Match, then iTunes should be the place where all music is combined. So if you sync you new iPhone with iTunes you should have all your music on every device synced with iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

When you connect your new phone on iTunes, click on the phone in the left column and then click on the Music tab at the top of the page:

[image: Itunes preview]

Make sure that the **Entire music library** radio button is selected (unlike in the screen shot) and no other option. This setting may have been inherited from your old phone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've already known how to transfer music from iPhone to iPhone with iTunes. And here I recommend you to do that via DropBox. Sign up for a Dropbox account and free Dropbox accounts come with 2 GB of space. If you have more music than that, you can pay for additional storage or try one of the other methods in this article.Install the Dropbox client on your computer.You can open the Dropbox folder by clicking the Dropbox icon in your System Tray or menu bar, and then clicking the Folder button.Wait for the music to upload.In addition, you should download the Dropbox app on your iPhone. Dropbox will stream any of the songs that you have stored on your Dropbox account as long as you have a network connection.

Comment: might work, but it's an expensive solution if your data is limited

Answer (score -1):

Just use a software called [WALTR](https://softorino.com/waltr/other/5-ways-put-mp3-on-iphone/). It may help you with transfering all your music from itunes to your new iphone.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.